# Как правильно задать параметр в requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, url, requests

Ссылка на документацию:
http://api.ontraport.com/doc/#pagination

Пример в документации:

```
[{
    "field":{"field":"email"},
    "op":"=",
    "value":{"value":"test@test.com"}
}]
```

Задать запрос нужно таким образом, чтобы получилось:

> https://api.ontraport.com/1/Contacts?range=50&condition=%5B%7B%20%20%20%20%20%22field%22%3A%7B%22field%22%3A%22email%22%7D%2C%20%20%20%20%20%22op%22%3A%22%3D%22%2C%20%20%20%20%20%22value%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22test%40test.com%22%7D%20%7D%5D

Как правильно преобразовать данный запрос под python requests

Comment: Ого, `json` в параметры запроса, мощно :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://api.ontraport.com/1/Contacts'
CONDITION = [{
    "field":{"field":"email"},
    "op":"=",
    "value":{"value":"test@test.com"}
}]
PARAMS = {
    'range': 50,
    'condition': str(CONDITION),
}
HEADERS = {
    'Api-Key': 'Key5678',
    'Api-Appid': '2_AppID_12345678',
}

rs = requests.get(URL, params=PARAMS, headers=HEADERS)
print(rs)
```

---

[Добавив отладку запросов requests](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/33326bb9cde49560104251b709e37408af79b9b4/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L10), увидел что `URI` получился таким:

```
send: b'GET /1/Contacts?range=50&condition=%5B%7B%27field%27%3A+%7B%27field%27%3A+%27email%27%7D%2C+%27op%27%3A+%27%3D%27%2C+%27value%27%3A+%7B%27value%27%3A+%27test%40test.com%27%7D%7D%5D HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.ontraport.com\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
```